# Let $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a positive function s.t. for all $M>0,f \in R([0,M])$. Which of the following statements are true?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, solution-verification

**Problem:**
Let $f:[0, \infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a positive function s.t. for all $ M > 0 $ it occurs that $ f $ is integrable on $ [0,M] $. Which of the following statements are true?

A. If $\lim _{x \rightarrow+\infty} f(x)=0$ then $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) d x$ exists and is finite.
B. If $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) d x$ exists and is finite then $\lim _{x \rightarrow+\infty} f(x)=0$.
C. If $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) d x$ exists and is finite then $\int_{0}^{\infty} f\left(x^{2}\right) d x$ exists and is finite.
D. None of the above.

**Attempt:**
I marked 'D' as the answer, here are my counter examples for A,B,C:
Counter-example for $ A$:
$ f(x)=\begin{cases} 0 &\text{if}\; x \in [0,1] \\\\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} & 1<x \; \end{cases} $

Counter-example for $ B$:  $ f(x)=\begin{cases} 1 &\text{if}\; x \in \mathbb{N} \\\\ 0 & else \; \end{cases} $

Counter example for $ C$: $ C $ is not correct, here's my disprove,
Assume for the sake of contradiction that $ \int_{0}^{\infty} f\left(x^{2}\right) d x $ exists and is finite.
$ \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x^2 ) d x = \{ u = x^2 , \sqrt{u} = x , du = 2x dx = 2\sqrt{u} dx  \} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f( u )}{ \sqrt{u} } d u $ .
By the Integral Direct comparison test, if we take $ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\frac{f( u )}{ \sqrt{u} }}{ \frac{1}{ \sqrt{u} }} du  = \frac{1}{2}  \int_{0}^{\infty} f( u ) du$ which converges to a finite, positive value, but $ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{ \sqrt{u} } du $ diverges. Hence, $ \frac{1}{2} \cdot \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f( u )}{ \sqrt{u} } d u $ diverges, a contradiction.

Was I correct? I'm not sure and I'll appreciate the help!

Note:  Using integral comparison test in the sense of comparing between integrals, like here [https://web.njit.edu/~bg263/Lecture](https://web.njit.edu/%7Ebg263/Lecture) notes and supplements/L19.pdf ( and not in the context of sums )

Comment: For C) you can just take $f(x)=\frac 1 {\sqrt x}$ for $0 <x<1$ and $0$ for $x \geq 1$.

Comment: You're right, haven't thought about that. Also, I noticed that my disprove was specious because I can't use the Integral Direct Comparison test on an integration that has two problematic points ( in this case, $0, \infty $ ) so it needs a little bit of fixing.

Comment: It really depends what is meant by "integrable" in this context. Does it mean that the (proper) Riemann integral exists? I believe this is what the term is often used to mean. On the other hand if "integrable" includes the possibility of having a converging improper integral, then Kavi Rama Murthy's comment provides a counterexample. If the first interpretation is the correct one then note that $\infty$ is the only problematic point because it is given that $f(x)$ is integrable in $[0,M]$ for any $M>0$. Do you know which of the two meanings of the word "integrable" is intended here?

Comment: @Snaw  I'm not really sure what the answer is because this is how the question appeared in my exam, I couldn't get in touch with my professor. Of-course, I did learn about Riemann Integrals in my course ( but not about Lebesgue integrals). In any-case, I don't see why the answer would be different given the fact that we want to find an $ f$ s.t. $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) d x$ exists and is finite.

Comment: You should check your lecture notes to see what the word "integrable" means. It either refers only to bounded functions on finite intervals or else it is expanded to also include converging improper integrals. This makes a difference, because if it means the former, then Kavi Rama Murthy's function is not integrable on $[0,M]$.

Comment: I don't have a strict answer to that in my lecture notes, I do have the following though: 
1. (Definition) ( Riemann Integrable ): Let $ f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}. $ We'll say $f$ is Riemann Integrable on $[a,b]$ if its integrable is equal to $I $ if for every $\epsilon > 0 $ there exists $ \delta > 0 $ s.t. for every partiton $ \Pi $ that satisfies $ \lambda(\Pi) < \delta $ and for every choice of appropriate points for $ \Pi $, $\{t_i\}$, we have $\left|S\left(f, \Pi,\left\{t_{i}\right\}\right)-I\right|<\varepsilon$ and in such a case we'll denote $I=\int_{a}^{b} f(t) d t=\int_{a}^{b} f$

Comment: 2. (Theorem) Let $ f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R} $. If $ f \in R([a,b]) $ then $f $ is bounded.

I think $f$ is supposed to be bounded on the finite interval it is defined if it to be Riemann-Integrable, because if not, then Kava Rama Murthy brought a counter-example to the theorem.

Comment: Yes, $f$ should be bounded in order for the (proper) Riemann integral to exist. You should see if when you defined improper Riemann integrals the word "integrable" was also used. In my course we said that "$\int_0^{\infty} f(x)\,dx$ converges" rather than say that $f(x)$ is integrable there, but I've seen that others allow the word "integrable" to include converging improper integrals, I don't remember in what book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your examples for A and B are great. Regarding C, your usage of the comparison test is incorrect. When comparing the integrals of $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ you should take the limit of $\frac{g(x)}{h(x)}$, rather than the limit of $\int \frac{g(x)}{h(x)}$. Here if we take your approach then we do not know that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ exists (per part B). Moreover, it seems you tried to prove that $\int f(x^2)\,dx$ would never be converging, which is certainly not true, for instance $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$ which becomes $f(x^2)=\frac{1}{x^4}$, both of which have a converging integral on $[1,\infty)$ (and one can zero them out at $[0,1)$ like the trick you used in part A).

Whether or not C is correct depends on the exact meaning of the word "integrable" and this should be checked in your lecture notes. It is customary to let "integrable" refer to having a proper Riemann integral, so that for instance $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ would not be integrable on $[0,1]$, even though its improper integral does converge on that interval. In case the word "integrable" is to include the case of a converging improper integral then a counterexample to C has been given in the comments. However, assuming that "integrable" refers strictly to proper Riemann integrals, then C is correct since it is given that $f(x)$ is integrable in $[0,M]$ for every $M>0$, so the only problem is at infinity. Intuitively then C should be correct since $f(x^2)$ approaches its asymptote at infinity faster than $f(x)$ does. To prove this rigorously, transform the integral as you have using $u=x^2$. Then

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x^2 )\, dx = \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f( u )}{ \sqrt{u} }\, du.$$
Split this into two integrals. The integral over $[0,1]$ converges by comparison with $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}\,du$, since $f(u)$ is bounded in $[0,1]$, so that
$$\frac{f(u)}{\sqrt{u}}\leq \frac{M}{\sqrt{u}}$$
and the integral of the right hand side over $[0,1]$ converges. The integral over $[1,\infty)$ also converges, by Dirichlet's test, since $\int_1^b f(u)\,du$ is bounded as it is convergent, and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}$ is decreasing and tends to $0$ as $u\to\infty$.